# CCLabelTTF can not print multiple value

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

[image]

i want to print multiple value using for loop. but something is missing.

thanks in advance.

Comment: please post you codes instead of screenshot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Syntax Error. It should be:

```
label1 = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", i] 
                            fontName:@"Times New Roman" 
                            fontSize:40];
```

Comment: is it possible to use NSString stringWithFormat: ?

Comment: `cocos2d` is Objective-C. Can't? If you didn't import `Foundation.framework`, do it. By default, it should be already imported.

Comment: sounds like daxesh is unaware that @".." is the same as a NSString* object